# Unit test in React requires construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Having this React component:

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/react';

export function MyExample() {
  return (
    <div>my example</div>
  );
}

export default {
  component: MyExample,
  title: 'MyExample'
} as Meta;
```

I want to write some unit tests for it, so this is the approach:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import MyExample from './MyExample.stories';

describe('MyExample', () => {
  it('should render MyExample successfully', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(<MyExample />);
    expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

However, it has an error. A red line appears under the render's argument stating:

> JSX element type 'MyExample' does not have any construct or call
> signatures

Any ideas how to fix this? I mention that it is done with Typescript.

Comment: `import MyExample` gives you the default exported object `{ component: MyExample,  title: 'MyExample' }`. So, you cannot call that, you need `MyExample.component` for the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyExample` in your code is not exported as default.

So you need to change your import statement to:

```js
import { MyExample } from './MyExample.stories'
// ...
```

You may want to use the eslint plugin `import` and the rule [import/no-named-as-default](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-named-as-default.md) to prevent this kind of error in the future.